# Where or how is the automatic update of GitHub and others activities?

Tags: support, status-planned, developer-story

In the previous jobs site, there was an amazing feature which populated my CV with all my activity on Stack Overflow, friends, GitHub, etc. This worked on the previous jobs site; now how do I update my CV with my last activities?

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that there used to be a feature with Stack Overflow Careers where you could import Github repos. This wasn't a robust implementation, but it was something. This feature unfortunately did not transition over to Developer Story. The main reasons for this are 1) time and 2) the feature had too many bugs for us to confidently launch with it.

Still, there is a way you can manually add Github repos.

1. Go to your Developer Story.
2. Go to "Add a new item" and click the "Open Source" icon. [image]
3. Then you can add your repo. [image]

We know this isn't ideal though. We are actively looking into creating a more automated way of adding repos to your Developer Story. Thanks for bringing this to our attention.

Comment: I'm proud of my question :D , but the feature with many bugs or not is better than nothing , I can't do about 100 updates by hand . Anyway what I got now, done by previous version is very good , I can always rearrange the entries on my CV ,  also give me a good perceptive what I have done lately , the feature had this bless , that do it for me .